# How do I get rid of a duplicate application?

Tags: 20.04

When I search my Applications for Discord I see 2 versions (see screenshot).

One opens Discord normally. The other prompts me to download an update then disappears. If I download the update and run it prompts me to Remove discord.

If I Remove discord, I just end up with the version that prompts me to download a new update.

Any suggestions how I can clean this mess up?[image]

At the bare minimum, I'd like to delete the faulty app (which I'm currently unable to do). I've sunk too many hours trying to delete the faulty app or mistakenly clicking on it.

I don't see it in `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/` or `/usr/local/share/applications/` btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to install applications in Ubuntu. For example, you can copy the application's file to the places they need to go manually, you can install a [Debian package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29), you can install an application via [Snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)) and others. If you install the same application with two or more of these methods, you can end up with multiple copies of the same application. Probably, this is what happened here.

Chances are, you installed one copy of the Discord client from a Debian package (a file ending with `.deb`) and another copy via Snap. You can check that with

```
dpkg -l '*discord*'
```

(I'm not aware of an official `apt` repository for Discord, so I'll stay on the `dpkg` layer for this answer)

If this prints a line for discord starting with `ii`, there's a copy of the Discord client installed from a Debian package. It should look similar to

```
ii  discord        0.0.11       amd64        All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers
```

Regarding Snap, you can list the installed Snaps with

```
snap list
```

The list printed by this command probably contains an entry for the Discord client, as well.

You can remove the reduntant installation with

```
dpkg -r discord
```

or

```
snap remove discord
```

respectively.

To find out which copy is working and which isn't, you just have to try. If you uninstalled the "wrong" copy, you just need to reinstall it. This is done by downloading the `*.deb` file from [https://discord.com/new](Discord's home page) and installing that with something similar to

```
dpkg -i discord-0.0.11.deb
```

or

```
snap install discord
```

respectively.

Comment: Yes, turns out one was a snap installation. `uninstall` didn't work but this did: `snap remove --purge discord-bartixxx`

Comment: @Snowcrash Glad it worked :) I corrected the snap command in the answer. That's one thing you'll run into with a lot of commands, it can get tricky to remember whether it's "uninstall" or "remove" or something else in each case ;)