# Duplicate Application Item in "show applications" ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons, launcher, snap

I have a duplicate Item for Android Studio in the "show applications" menu, with only one of them actually working. Why did that happen, and how can I remove the icon that is not working?

Comment: I do appreciate your spirit of sharing knowledge and Stack Exchange [encourages](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) such things. But since this is a Q&A site, all posts here are expected to be in Q&A format. I'd encourage you to [edit] your post, redact answer/solution and post that as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of a duplicate application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266206/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-duplicate-application)

Comment: @vanadium kinda, its a similar problem, but not quite the same

Comment: and thank yall for pointing out that i can mark this post as self answer, i am pretty new here though, so how do i do that exactly? :D

Comment: You have to post an answer using the text below. Then edit the question to have only the problem details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Icons get stored as `.desktop` files, and are normally either in `/usr/share/applications` (this is the Systemwide location) or `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.
In my case, i had installed Android Studio with `apt`, following the instructions [here](https://linuxhint.com/install_android_studio_ubuntu/), so i didn't think of looking into any other directory than the ones listed. I found a file named `android-studio.desktop` in the Systemwide directory, so i deleted it, to see if it was the one that didn't work, which it was not. So I searched around for a while, in the folders and googled a lot, but didn't seem to find anything, until i found [this](https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/3076/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-entries-from-dash-on-18-04) post, where someone had the same problem but in Ubuntu 18.04.

So it turns out I actually installed or tried to install Android Studio with Snap before, and for whatever reason, when i removed it, it seemed to have kept the `.desktop` file used to start the snap variant of Android Studio. And snap doesn't use the Systemwide location for .desktop files, but creates its own directory at: `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`

LONG STORY SHORT: removing the `android-studio.desktop` file  in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` fixed it and only the Icon in the Systemwide location stayed.

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266206/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-duplicate-application) refers to the problem of having the same application installed two times, which might also fix your problem, if both icons do something, if they don't, my solution could help