# How to get rid of duplicate / not working app icon

Tags: software-installation, duplicate-files

I have two Spotify icons showing. I already followed the instructions in  [How do I get rid of a duplicate application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266206/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-duplicate-application), but the app that was removed was the working one.  Now I want to restore the previous working app and remove the duplicate non-working icon.

[image]

Comment: @AkshajSingla this worked. This means I tried to install Spotify as a snap package and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

- Find the relevant `.desktop` files on your system with the command

  ```
  find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Name=Spotify" {} \; 2>/dev/null
  ```
- Inspect the contents of the files you found. Look at the `Exec=` line to learn which executable they are calling. That the icon is in the application overview indicates that the executable is present.
- Try each of the command after `Exec=` of the different launchers on the command line. One will not work, the other will.

The issue indeed may be a faulty installation. First try uninstalling the faulty application: that will automatically remove the `.desktop` launcher. Manually deleting the  `.desktop` launcher also will eliminate it from your overview, but prefer to remove the faulty application in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt install spotify` and `sudo snap remove spotify`. If this removed the correct app then reverse snap with apt.

As you said in the comments, it worked.